# How to extract the correlation matrix features to a list if their values is beyond a certain threshold

Tags: python, pandas

After a read the first chapter in the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Sci-kit Learn and Tensorflow" I wanted to do my own little project and learn a bit. So I wanted to make it simple and only use simple linear regression with features that correlate with Sale Price above abs(0.1).

```
corr_matrix = raw_train_data.corr()
corr_matrix['SalePrice'].sort_values(ascending = False)

SalePrice           1.00
OverallQuality      0.79
YearBuilt           0.52
etc
```

I tried something like this:

```
features = []
for feature, value in corr_matrix['SalePrice']:
    if abs(value) >= 0.1:
        features.append(feature)
    else:
        pass
```

But it gives out error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object
```

Can somebody help and explain this to me, I am still inexperienced with ML and data manipulation in python. Thanks!

Comment: You should put whole code which could reproduces the error.

Comment: `corr_matrix['SalePrice']` will just return the column as a series. When you do `for item in series:` it iterates over the values, so it can't unpack `1.00` into a `feature, value` tuple. Try any of boolean masking, series.filter, series.query

Comment: Have you already tried `corr_matrix['SalePrice'].iteritems():` in place of `corr_matrix['SalePrice']:`?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
for feature, value in corr_matrix['SalePrice']
```

with

```
for feature, value in corr_matrix['SalePrice'].iteritems():
```

gets the job done!
Thanks @jottbe for the solution and all the others for replying!

Answer (score 0):

If your using dataframe, why don't you simply use 'corr_matrix[abs(corr_matrix['SalePrice'])>= 0.1]' instead of for loop?

Please provide more information about your **data structure**!